# ISSP data: calculating percentage of respondent answers on a particular item

Tags: r, function, matrix, survey

Probably a pretty basic question, and hopefully one not repeated elsewhere.  I’m looking at some ISSP survey data in R, and I made a separate data frame for respondents who answered “Government agencies” on one of the questions:

```
gov.child<-data[data$"V33"=="Government agencies",]
```

Then I used the table function to see how many total respondents answered that way in each country (C_ALPHAN is the variable name for country):

```
table(gov.child$C_ALPHAN)
```

Then I made a matrix of this table:

```
gov.child.matrix<-as.matrix(table(gov.child$C_ALPHAN))
```

So I now have a two-column matrix with just the two-letter country code (the C_ALPHAN code) and the number of people who answered “Government agencies.”  But I want to know what percentage of respondents in those countries answered that way, so I need to divide this number by the total number of respondents for that country.

Is there some way (a function maybe?) to, after adding a new column, tell R that for each row, it has to divide the number in column two by the total number of rows in the original data set that correspond to the country code in column one (i.e., the n for that country)?  Or should I just manually make a vector with the n for each country, which is available on the ISSP website, and add it to the matrix? I'm loathe to to that because of the possibility of making a data entry error, but maybe that's the best way.

Comment: Wouldn't `table(data$C_ALPHAN)` give you the total respondents by country? Then just merge the two tables based on the country codes (see `?merge`) and divide.

Comment: jlhoward, of course!  I don't know why that didn't occur to me.  THANKS!  Much simpler.